# Reading images from a .cbz archive

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory, bufferedimage

I want to read images inside a .CBZ archive and store them inside an ArrayList. I have tried the following solution but it has, at least, 2 problems.

1. I get an OutOfMemory error after adding 10-15 images to the ArrayList
2. There must be a better way of getting the images inside the ArrayList instead of writing them on a temp file and reading that again.

---

```
public class CBZHandler {
final int BUFFER = 2048;
ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

public void extractCBZ(ZipInputStream tis) throws IOException{
    ZipEntry entry;
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    if(!images.isEmpty())
        images.clear();
    while((entry = tis.getNextEntry()) != null){
        System.out.println("Extracting " + entry.getName());
        int count;
        FileOutputStream fos =  new FileOutputStream("temp");
        dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,BUFFER);
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
        while ((count = tis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
               dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        dest.flush();
        dest.close();
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("temp"));
        images.add(img);
    }
    tis.close();
}
}
```

Comment: ImageIO reads from an InputStream. Why don't you pass the ZipInputStream (`tis`) to `ImageIO.read()`? What's the size of the images (in bytes), and what's the size of the heap of the JVM?

Comment: Knowing the resolution (width*height, maybe *colordepth) of these images would also help in estimating memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The "OutOfMemoryError" *may* or may not be inherent in the amount of data you're trying to store in memory. You may need to change your maximum heap size. However, you can certainly avoid writing to disk - just write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead, then you can get at the data as a byte array - potentially creating a `ByteArrayInputStream` round it if you need to. Do you definitely need to add them in your list as `BufferedImage` rather than (say) keeping each as a `byte[]`?

Note that if you're able to use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) it makes the "extract data from an `InputStream`" bit very easy:

```
byte[] data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(tis);
```

Comment: It looks strange to me that I run OOM since that routine is all my code does up til now. Thanks for the ByteArrayOutputStream hint. What would be the advantages of storing them as bytes ?

Comment: @AlfioCastorina: Well imagine that these are some images with a high level of compression - the `BufferedImage` may well be converting it into an in-memory bitmap representation for each pixel, which would be *much* bigger than the data in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Each `BufferedImage` will typically require significantly more memory than the `byte[]` from which it is constructed.  Cache the `byte[]` and stamp each one out to an image as needed.